# Installer goes black on Thinkpad T495 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a brand new Thinkpad T495. I've disabled Secure Boot and enable legacy and UEFI (the "both" setting). Now when I go to install Ubuntu the installer goes black (See the picture below).

Now if I go to "Security Chip" in the BIOS and enable it, the installer does **not** go black, but then it won't allow me to install Ubuntu and prompts me to "turn off Bitlocker" in Windows. However, it is already off? Any ideas? It's running an AMD Ryzen 7 chip.

[image]

Comment: Guess that's the first TP that will not run out of the box with linux. It has been [certified for preinstalled](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201905-27049), which means there might be video drivers for AMD Picasso and linux. But not in Ubuntu. Try to add the `--nomodeset`option before starting up.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** - So eventhough BitLocker was not enabled on Windows, the drive was still encrypted. Also, the live USB installation needed to be re-installed as the failed attempt to install messed it up. The solution was to decrypt the drive in Windows and re-install the live USB and install Ubuntu.